# Checking Pixels in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image with 3 colors in matlab which value `0`, `128`, and `255`. for example:

```
255  255  255   255  128  255   0   255  255  128   0   255
255   0   255   255  128  255  255   0   255  128  255  255
255   0   255    0   128  255  255  255  255  128  255   0     
255  255   0    255  128  255  255   0   255  128  255  255
255   0    0    255  128   0   255  255   0   128  255   0
```

First, I want to check the pixels of the index `(1,1)` to `(1,5)`.

If there is pixel value `0` (black), then the pixels of the index `(1,1)` to `(1,5)` is changed to `128` (gray), if none, then the pixels are changed to `0` (white).

Second, I want to do these steps again, checking of the index `(2,1)` to `(2,5)`, `(3,1)` to `(3,5)`, through to the bottom, then continue to the next, to the index `(1,6)` to `(1,10)`, `(2,6)` to `(2,10)`, through to the bottom, then went to the index `(1,11)` to `(1,end)`, `(2,11)` to `(2,end)`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you absolutely need to do this sequentially? It sounds like you need to do this for each group of the form (n, (5*m : 5*m +1)). If so, you can do all of the tests simultaneously by reshaping the matrix into a 3d matrix of blocks which are 5 elements wide. Also I am assuming that you meant "if none, then the pixels are changed to `255` (white)", not `0`.

Suppose your image is called `myImage`, then

```
numBlocks = numel(myImage)/(5*size(myImage,1));
% Generate a 3D matrix each of which is 5 elements long in dimension 2. Note reshape will throw an error if numblocks is fractional
foo = reshape(myImage,size(myImage,1),5,numBlocks); 
blackTest = any(foo==0,2);
result = blackTest * 128 + ~blackTest*255; % result for each block
output = reshape(repmat(result,[1 5 1]),size(myImage));
```

This reorganises your image into a 3d matrix, where each submatrix corresponding to each "layer" of the 3d matrix is 5 elements wide. For the whole 3d matrix it checks whether any of the elements in dimension 2 are zero, leaving a logical matrix `foo` of length 1 in dimension 2. `foo` consists of logical ones and zeros, which in MATLAB can also be treated as numerical ones and zeros. So it multiplies `foo` by 128 (for grey output value) and adds the logical inverse of `foo` multiplied by 255, to get your white output values. Finally it repeats the matrix back to 5-element-wide blocks and restores it to its original dimensions.

Edit: Note that as mentioned in the code comment, this code won't work if your original image isn't a multiple of 5 pixels wide. To fix this you'd have to create a special case, or use a loop to step through each 5-element-wide block. In fact that might be a better approach all round:

```
index = 1;
output = zeros(size(myImage));

while index < size(myImage,2)
blockEnd = min(index+4,size(myImage,2));
blackTest = any(myImage(:,index:blockEnd)==0,2);
blackTest = blackTest(:,ones(1,5));
output(1:end,index:blockEnd) = blackTest * 128 + ~blackTest*255;
index = index+5;
end
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep for commenting privileges, so I'll mention here that zenpoy's answer is similar to but more elegant than my first solution above. As far as I can tell it also suffers from the same multiple-of-5 limitation.

Comment: thanks for helping. 

I've found a way for the case isn't a multiple of 5 pixels wide. I add the column to be a multiple of 5, then the end result I took the beginning of matrix only.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but you'll need to make sure that the columns you add don't contain zeros or you'll skew your result.

Answer (score 1):

```
% generate matrix
rand_data = randi(10,10);
I = zeros(10);
I(rand_data < 6 & rand_data > 3) = 128;
I(rand_data >= 6) = 255;

% here's the code
I = reshape(I',5,[])';
mask = repmat(any(I == 0,2),5,1);
I(mask) = 128;
I(~mask) = 255;
I = reshape(I',10,[])';
```